# Terminology for network interfaces on router?

Tags: networking, router

What is the correct terminology for the network interface that is connected towards the Internet on a router?

And what is the correct terminology for the network interface that is connected towards the LAN on a router?

Answer (score 2):

External interface = interface connected to Internet.

Internal interface = interface connected to LAN.

Answer (score 2):

As kafka says, but let me add something normally used:

External interface = interface connected to Internet = WAN interface

Internal interface = interface connected to LAN = LAN interface.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your router, people may call it something but your router may label it something else. They are each as accurate as the next.

Internet facing

- Outside
- Untrust
- WAN
- Public
- External

Internal facing

- Inside
- Trust
- LAN
- Private
- Internal